# Is it valid to use more than one thead or tfoot element in a table?

Tags: javascript, html

Imagine a list of lists similar to this:

```js
var list = [
  { name: 'group1', 
    items: [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]
  },
  { name: 'group2', 
    items: [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]
  },
  etc...
]
```

Now forgetting the whole "tables are for data not design" argument, I wanted to display a single table for `list` and have a seperate `<thead>` and `<tbody>` for each entry in `list`.

Is this technically valid?  This works in the browser, but my [spider senses are tingling on this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3206239/multiple-thead-tbody-design).

Answer (score 137, accepted):

You can have as many `<tbody>` elements as you want, but no more than one each of `<thead>` and `<tfoot>`. [Reference](https://www.w3.org/TR/html/tabular-data.html#the-table-element):

> **Content model:**
>
> In this order: optionally a caption element, followed
>   by zero or more colgroup elements, **followed optionally by a thead
>   element, followed by either zero or more tbody elements or one or more
>   tr elements, followed optionally by a tfoot element**, optionally
>   intermixed with one or more script-supporting elements.

Comment: And you can use `th scope=rowgroup` inside a regular `tr` to describe each `tbody`. See ["Example"](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/tables.html#the-th-element).

Answer (score 12):

There's at most one `thead` and one `tfoot` [allowed](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/table.html#table), so you shouldn't create additional headers. After all the `th` in a `thead` gives a meaning to your columns, like "time of day", "temperature", "amount of cats currently on fire".

If the entries in your list are related they should all be in the same table and you should provide a fitting header to display that relation.

If the entries are actually unrelated you should provide a single table for every of those. You can still apply the same CSS on every table to get a nice result.

Comment: "If the entries in your list are related they should all be in the same table and you should provide a fitting header to display that relation" -- I think that repeating the same header in a very long table would sometimes be desirable so the user doesn't have to scroll back to the top to remember what the columns are. Of course, there are other solutions to this (e.g. JavaScript to use a "sticky" table header or CSS on table row elements to make it visually different than the other rows).

Answer (score 5):

I consider it to be just like `id` attributes.  They are supposed to be unique, but you can actually re-use it in the same page and you can still select it.  **That said, just because it can be done doesn't mean it should be done.**

I would recommend against it.

Comment: There's nothing at all wrong with having more than one `<tbody>`, but according the spec there can be just one `<thead>` and one `<tfoot>`.

Comment: From what I can tell, he wasn't suggesting to do it at all.  Just saying it worked in the browser?

Answer (score 0):

### Pseudo-table

As said by others, you can't have several `thead` nor `tfoot` in a `table`. But you can mimic them considering each `tbody` as a *peuso-nested-table*.

#### Pseudo-heading

Considering you can have as many `tbody` as you want, there is stil, if not empty, a first row `tr` in each one. You can consider this first row as *pseudo-heading*. You can have `th` cells in it. You can apply them a specific CSS style with the CSS selector `tbody tr:first-child th`. You can select those rows and make stuff with JavaScript with :

```js
document.querySelectorAll("tbody tr:first-child").forEach(myStuffFunction);
```

or for a specific table :

```js
myTable.querySelectorAll("tbody tr:first-child").forEach(myTableStuffFunction);
```

#### Pseudo-footer

The same thing can be done for *pseudo-footer* with the CSS selector `tbody tr:last-child th`

#### Peudo-body

*Not tested*

Without *pseudo-footer*, the *peudo-body* is composed with rows selected with `tbody tr:first-child ~ tr` (all sibling rows), or with `tbody tr :not(:first-child)`.

With a *pseudo-footer*, the *peudo-body* is composed with rows selected with `tbody tr:not(:first-child):not(:last-child)`.