# AngularJS: ng-form + ng-repeat-start

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a table with an `ng-repeat-start` that generates 4 rows per item in an array.

For each `ng-repeat`, I'm creating an `ng-form` to validate each item and generate error messages on a item by item basis.

What's the correct way to structure the HTML, so that the `ng-form` is accessible from all of the rows generated between the `ng-repeat-start` and the `ng-repeat-end`?

```
<ng-form name="allItemsForm" novalidate>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Items</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-form="itemForm" ng-repeat-start="item in ctrl.items">
                <td>
                    <input ng-model="item.name" name="name" required />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <textarea ng-model="item.comment" name="comment" required></textarea>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Error for name: {{ itemForm.name.$invalid }}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat-end>
                <td>Error for comment: {{ itemForm.comment.$invalid }}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <button type="submit" ng-disabled="allItemsForm.$invalid">
        SUBMIT
    </button>
</ng-form>
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/7163osn2/4/

Comment: 'so that the ng-form is accessible from all of the rows', what do you want to achieve?

Comment: @shershen i've added an example. I want to use the extra rows to hold information about the errors that appear in the first few rows.

Comment: ```<tr ng-repeat-end><td>Error for comment: {{itemForm | json}}</td></tr>``` is available in those  rows isn't it?

Comment: @shershen yeah that's available! Annoyingly it only contains the validation objects for the "name" input in this example, but contains nothing about the "comment" input

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16155425/1977007) it's valid to have multiple `tbody` elements inside of a `table`. All `td` cells will still match up to their parent `th` cell as they would normally.

It also removes the need for the `ng-repeat-start`, so you're able to go back to the using a standard `ng-repeat`.

An update to my example in the original question: https://jsfiddle.net/7163osn2/5/

W3 HTML Markup [reference](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/table.html#table)