# How to separate pandas DF into different variables?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

This is a follow up question from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38417462/python-selenium-scraping-tbody/38417528?noredirect=1#comment64242035_38417528)

I have the below code which I use to scrape from a website

```
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")
    for thead in soup.select(".data-point-container table thead"):
        tbody = thead.find_next_sibling("tbody")

        table = "<table>%s</table>" % (str(thead) + str(tbody))

        df = pandas.read_html(str(table), header=0, index_col=0)[0]
        df = df.drop(['Unnamed: 6'], axis=1)

        # Renaming Columns to just have FY-YEAR
        for each_column in df.columns:
            if each_column[:3] == "LTM":
                df.rename(columns={each_column: "Last 12 Months"}, inplace=True)
            else:
                df.rename(columns={each_column: each_column[:6]}, inplace=True)

        df = df.T

        print(df)
        print("-------------------------------------")
```

Upon execution, it produces this result.

[image: capture 1]

The screenshot just shows 2 dataframes, theres a total of 6 dataframes on code execution.

What I want to do is to merge them together, so that on the row axes, it just shows `FY2012, FY2013, FY2014, FY2015, Last 12 Months`, and on the column axis, it would show a combination of all the rows from the 6 `Dataframe` it scrapped from the website.

I think I can do this by separating it into different `variables` and use a form of `df.join()` method to achieve this. But I'm having trouble is separating this `df` into different variables in the first place..

What do you think?

**Update**

Initially I thought I could just do a `print(df[0])` but this gives me a `keyerror:0`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Pandas merge only certain columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17978133/python-pandas-merge-only-certain-columns)

Comment: @Kartik, no it is not..