# Jaws Is reading partial data on insert + down key press

Tags: java, html, jaws-screen-reader

Table contains 2 thread JAWS read only 1st thread and body it won't read next thread it direcly skip that part, how to resolve this . when i use insert+down arrow key it should read all data one by one.

```
<div class="span16 m-t-2x width-100">
                            <table class="table planValResultsTbl" id="planValResultsTbl">
                                <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th class="pad-table align-left">Member</th>
                                    <th class="pad-table align-left">Age</th>
                                    <th class="pad-table align-left">DOB</th>
                                    <th class="pad-table align-left">Coverage Start Date</th>
                                    <th class="pad-table align-left">Non-Capped Premium</th>
                                    <th class="pad-table align-left">Capped Premium</th>
                                </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                
                                    <tr align="char">
                                        <td class="pad-table">
                                            Primary Applicant</td>
                                        <td class="pad-table align-left">28</td>
                                        <td class="pad-table align-left">
                                            08/08/1994
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="pad-table align-left">
                                            08/15/2022
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="pad-table align-left noncapped" style="text-align: left">$164.00</td>
                                        <td class="pad-table align-left capped" style="text-align: left">$164.00</td>
                                    </tr>
                                
                                </tbody>
                                <thead>
                                <tr align="char">
                                    <th colspan="6" class="pad-table total">
                                        Capped Premium Total   &emsp;
                                        <span class="cappedPremiumCurrencyVal">$164.00</span></th>
                                </tr>
                                </thead>
                            </table>
                        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't add more than one `<thead>` in a single `<table>` element ([see this previous SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16155396/is-it-valid-to-use-more-than-one-thead-or-tfoot-element-in-a-table) and [the W3C HTML `<table>` spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/tables.html#the-table-element) for reference).

You need to place your last row either inside the `<tbody>` element, or use the `<tfoot>` element instead.

For example:

```
<div class="span16 m-t-2x width-100">
    <table class="table planValResultsTbl" id="planValResultsTbl">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="pad-table align-left">Member</th>
                <th class="pad-table align-left">Age</th>
                <th class="pad-table align-left">DOB</th>
                <th class="pad-table align-left">Coverage Start Date</th>
                <th class="pad-table align-left">Non-Capped Premium</th>
                <th class="pad-table align-left">Capped Premium</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr align="char">
                <td class="pad-table">Primary Applicant</td>
                <td class="pad-table align-left">28</td>
                <td class="pad-table align-left">08/08/1994</td>
                <td class="pad-table align-left">08/15/2022</td>
                <td class="pad-table align-left noncapped" style="text-align: left">$164.00</td>
                <td class="pad-table align-left capped" style="text-align: left">$164.00</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <tr align="char">
                <th class="pad-table total" colspan="6">Capped Premium Total &emsp; <span class="cappedPremiumCurrencyVal">$164.00</span></th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
</div>
```

I tested the code above using Chrome and JAWS 2022 and it read the whole table using <kbd>Insert</kbd> + <kbd>Down Arrow</kbd>, including the bottom row.